# Branding identity - different font for email

Tags: fonts, branding, identity, e-mail

We are developing new identity for our company. For print material we decided to go with Helvetica font.

However we get into serious discussion about font for email. To achieve some consistency, we are pretty much limited to system fonts like Arial, Verdana, etc.

Is it normal practise to use two different fonts for print material and email?

For web content we invested in typekit and it is working ok, we are just struggling with email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it normal practice to use two different fonts for print material and email?

Yes. Actually, it's normal practice do not specify *any* font in email. Email is text and not everyone wants HTML formatted email. And most people don't want to have to download a font just to view their email--especially on a mobile network.

Comment: I would like to add that even if you sent me a html email i would only see the text in a monospaced font over a terminal.